# Docker-compose is not reading env variable COMPOSE_FILE

Tags: python, django, linux, docker, devops

I am using django cookiecutter configuration with Docker and I can not make docker-compose read $COMPOSE_FILE env variable.

I did this

```
export COMPOSE_FILE=local.yml
```

And this is the outcome when a I run either docker-compose up or build:

```
Can't find a suitable configuration file in this directory or any
        parent. Are you in the right directory?

        Supported filenames: docker-compose.yml, docker-compose.yaml
```

Comment: You're running `docker-compose` in the exact same shell as you ran the `export` command?  There's not, say, a `sudo` or anything else involved?

Comment: Yes its the same shell, and yes I used sudo. It is not working with all that.

Comment: `sudo` resets the environment.  Does the `sudo -E` option make a difference?  (Please include the _exact_ command you ran in your question.)

Comment: Yes it did! With -E flag it works!